# Angular image tag (button) disabled not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a image as a button (save). When the form loads by default I will have value in the fields that time save button should in disable mode if user click the image (button) no method should not call but if the user edit the email id save button should be enable actually I tried giving like below but that is not working.

HTML code

```html
<mat-toolbar class="secondary-menu">
    <a>
        <img [disabled]="isButtonEnable" style="height: 26px;margin: 0 5px;cursor: pointer;" src="../../../assets/img/save.jpg" (click)="emailID()" title="Save" />
    </a>
</mat-toolbar>
```

And in TS I have initial value I set as

```js
isButtonEnable = true;
```

And in the emailID method I have enabled the `isButtonEnable = false;`.

Here is my HTML form

```html
<form [formGroup]="generalform" novalidate>                  
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Email" maxlength="250" formControlName="emailId" />
        <mat-icon matSuffix>email</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Phone number" maxlength="10" formControlName="phoneNumber" />
        <mat-icon matSuffix>phone</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

But the above way is not working. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: please don't close here i have wrongly put but in my code it is disabled

Comment: Have you tried triggering change detection manually?

Answer (score 0):

Disabled only works on form elements and doesn't work on image tag.

Try putting the disabled on the `a` tag.

```
<mat-toolbar class="secondary-menu">
<a [disabled]="isButtonEnable">
    <img style="height: 26px;margin: 0 5px;cursor: pointer;" src="../../../assets/img/save.jpg" (click)="emailID()" title="Save" />
</a>
```